# How to load SVGLoader with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I am trying to follow this tutorial in the documentation to bring some SVG's into my three.js project: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/SVGLoader

My code is as follows:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
var loader = new THREE.SVGLoader(); 

loader.load( 
  //loads asset
  'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vroom-emails/artifact-4-hover.svg', 

  // called when the asset is loaded
  function ( doc ) {
    scene.add( new THREE.SVGObject(doc) );

  },
  // loading in progress
  function (xhr) {
    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded'); 
  },
  // called when loading has errors
  function (error) {
    console.log('An error happened');
  }
);
```

I am loading in the THREE.js file as well as the SVGLoader: 
https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js

When I try to run, I am getting a console error that the SVGObject is not a constructor.

I'm following the documentation as an intro and it's sort of frustrating to hit a roadblock so early. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for this but the documentation page is actually deprecated. Please use the following example as your starter template: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_svg

Comment: Fixed in `dev`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/b059cd9a781d06f4e75655b2c2d2f40fe726ba2e